# Is mutex correctly implemented and how do I dispose it?

Tags: .net, dispose, mutex, idisposable, waithandle

I am reviewing some code and one of the code analysis (fxCop) warnings has gotten me very confused. The code implements a few [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)'s by creating variables at the start of the class, similar to this:

```
private Mutex myMutex = new Mutex();
```

fxCop is popping up with a message saying that I must implement IDisposable for the class as the Mutex class implements it - this is warning [CA1001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182172.aspx). However looking at Mutex it has no dispose method.

Turns out that Mutex uses a [SafeWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safewaithandle.aspx) (which implements IDisposable - guessing this is what fxCop is picking up), but mutex doesn't actually dispose it via the standard disposable pattern. It has a private method which is assigned to a delegate using the [RuntimeHelpers.CleanupCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.cleanupcode.aspx), which as I understand it means it will be run on an exception.

This brings up two questions:

1. Is Mutex implemented correctly? If there is no exception in the Mutex then the SafeWaitHandle will never be disposed.
2. What should I call in my dispose to cleanup the mutex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Mutex` *explicitly implements* `IDisposable.Dispose` through its base class `WaitHandle`. It exposes the `Dispose` functionality through its public `Close` method (also inherited from `WaitHandle`), which is a valid implementation of the dispose pattern, [according to the guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx):

> Occasionally a domain-specific name is
>   more appropriate than Dispose. For
>   example, a file encapsulation might
>   want to use the method name Close. In
>   this case, implement Dispose privately
>   and create a public Close method that
>   calls Dispose. (...) You
>   can replace Close with a method name
>   appropriate to your domain.

Several classes in `System.IO` do it this way as well.

Comment: doh, of course it does :) The moment I saw that the gears turned and it made sense.

Answer (score 0):

using the Close () function still generate [CA2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms182289.aspx) under VS 2013 Pro Update 2. 
The Dispose () function is not reachable because of its protection level.

So, is there a mistake or is this a bug in Code Analysis from VS ?

EDIT : 
Solved using this code :

```
Mutex MyApplicationMutex = null;
try
{
  MyApplicationMutex = new Mutex(true, Program.g_ApplicationMutexName);
  if (MyApplicationMutex.WaitOne(0, false))
  {
    ...
  }
}
finally
{
  // Dispose Mutex
  if (MyApplicationMutex != null)
    MyApplicationMutex.Close();
 }
```